# Retagging [find][replace] questions with [find-and-replace]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Please retag [questions tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find+replacement) with [find](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find)[replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/replacement) with the
[find-and-replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find-and-replace) tag.
I know I could do it myself, manually, but I thought it would be better to post about it here on meta first.

I've posted the same question on [meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157237/retagging-findreplace-questions-with-find-and-replace).

Comment: FYI `[tag:find]` refers to a Linux command line utility

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Should I retag them manually and wait for `[status-completed]`?

Comment: @tempy no. there's no need to retag [tag:find] which stands for an existing use to something else

Comment: @Sathya I'm only referring to [these questions](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find+replacement).